# mongodb aggregrade query like sql for select

Tags: mongodb

In mongodb, how can write this query:

```
select sum(marks) as marks from `student`;
```

how can write this query in Mongodb

Comment: SO is not a coding service, please read the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
db.students.aggregate(
[{
    $group:{
      _id:null, 
      marks: {$sum:"$marks"}}
 }])
```

look into the [docu](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) for more information